# how to make a child div not to exceed its parent width if child's width is dynamic

Tags: css, jsp

In my jsp, I have a div whose width is determined by a javabean value. Basically it is being used to fill a bar. Some times the values are greater than 100, so the width becomes 300% (for example), thus going out of the parent's boundary.

I need to know, how I can limit the child div's width so that it doesn't exceed the parent boundary.

Thank you.

Comment: for some reason, width:0 on the parent helped me.

Answer (score 6):

I just used a combination of the previous responses and it worked for me.
In my case I din't want to hardcode any pixel values but leave my child element fluid to grow and shrink to its parent element width.

Used for parent `overflow: hidden;` and for the child `width: 100% !important;`

Also noticed that the child doesn't have to be the direct child of the parent for this to work. For the record, my parent element is a Flex Container with `flex-basis: 66%;` which translates to a relative width in the Flexbox concept.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the following CSS to the parent div:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Or you might want to try the CSS `max-width` property on the child-div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **width:100% !important** on child div.This means it will fill only the parent div space only.

Alternatively you can also go for **max-width** and **min-width** concept.